# Why am I unable to SELECT the Gnome.gnomeName field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

An image of my sql statement

[image]

When i try to run this I get the error

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'gnomeName' as part of an aggregate function.

I know this is a very stupid question but i have very little experience with SQL and am having a really hard time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't Group By `gnomeID`.

Use: `Group By Gnome.gnomeName` .

Answer (score 0):

By using [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator, your output result should be either part of group by condition or an aggregation group.

Assume one gnomeID is linked to one gnomeName, you can change the group by condition to (gnomeID, gnomeName) to get the result you want.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(GnomePurchase.quanity) AS [total],gnomeName
FROM Gnome, GnomePurchase
WHERE Gnome.descripton like '*solar*' AND Gnome.gnomeID = GnomePurchase.gnomeID
GROUP BY Gnome.gnomeID,gnomeName
```

Next, you should use [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) instead of product join.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(GnomePurchase.quanity) AS [total],gnomeName
FROM Gnome 
INNER JOIN GnomePurchase 
ON Gnome.gnomeID = GnomePurchase.gnomeID 
WHERE Gnome.descripton like '*solar*' 
GROUP BY Gnome.gnomeID, gnomeName
```